# Is the creation of linux shared libraries consistent between linux x86_64 and arm64 architectures?

Tags: gcc, c, shared-library, architecture

I'm wondering if the way we create shared libraries is the same between these two architectures.

Let's say I have the file `fx.c` that contains some function definitions, so I would create a shared library like this:

```
gcc -fPIC -c fx.c -o fx.o
gcc -shared fx.o -o libtest.so
```

1. Is this way of creating shared libraries the same in x86_64 and arm64?
2. Is it true that shared libraries created in this way are shared by different processes and only one copy of it will reside in memory?

Comment: This probably is better suited for Stack Overflow as it's more or less a pure programming question, though hypothetical and not concrete and might be closed on Stack Overflow.

Comment: If this is about the Linux API or *nix systems and *nix only then it would also be on topic on [unix.se]. If Kode can clarify the scope (please edit and tell us what systems you are asking about), we can move to U&L, @ThomasWard.

Comment: @terdon, the scope is Ubuntu x86_64 or arm64

Comment: This isn't about Ubuntu or distribution choice though, it will be about the kernel. Does that mean your question is only about the Linux kernel then? If so, then yes you could ask on [unix.se] instead although I would say it's on topic here too.

Answer (score 1):

## Is this way of creating shared libraries the same in x86_64 and arm64?

It should be the same.

I extrapolated this from https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Implicit-Rules , and major build systems seem to agree that the command should be called with the same arguments on both platforms. This is especially true when automating cross-compiling to many targets. Advanced use cases may differ when you want to use certain flags that are named differently or exclusive to each architecture.

## Is it true that shared libraries created in this way are shared by different processes and only one copy of it will reside in memory?

On Ubuntu, this is true. See `strace` and `cat /proc/*/maps` to see the non-private `mmap` in action.

Unlike what the comments say, this is not a pure programming or a kernel-only question. This depends on the dynamic linker (`/lib/ld-linux.so`) that the distro ships with. A hypothetical distro could ship a dynamic linker that properly shares memory using `mmap` on x86_64, but ship one that does `memcpy` on arm64. However there is no reason for a distro to make that choice, and I don't know of any existing ones.